# R programming: how to reshape a 2-D array into a 3-D array based on given lat and lon?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, reshape2

I have a large 2-D matrix (1412729 rows by 5 columns), where the first two columns are latitude and longitude, and the next three columns are the concentration data by year. E.g,

lat | lon | PM2014 | PM2015 | PM2016

there are 1412729 rows of data.

I want to create a 3-D array from this dataset, where lat and lon are the rows and columns (non-repeating) and the 3rd dimension are the 3 years. The values in each 2-D slice should be the PM data for each year. Ultimately, I want to do this so that I can write the data out in netCDF format. I've searched and searched online, but can't find an example quite like this.

Comment: I think your geometric intuition for how you want this to work is leading you astray from how it actually works. Currently all your data  is arranged by rows, with the columns dictating which part of the data you want. so basically your latitude and longitude are forced grouped together. If you were to make this 3D with latitude, longitude, and three years of data, you could potentially be searching for data on a longitude and latitude you don't actually have information for. You could totally just shove all this into a 3D array, but it probably won't work the way it sounds like you want it to

Comment: Right, because there is no data for over the ocean regions. I'm thinking I need to make a raster object, since I know the lat and lon grid system, however, I don't know how to put values into the raster object from my table.

Comment: I suppose you could create a 3D array where the first two are lat and lon, however you would need to loop through and compare the lat and lon combinations to those you have stored and set the 3D values to be some value you can associate with "no data" so that if you're checking them automatically your system will be able to ignore the data at those locations

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I found the way via Section 4.2 here: http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/week04-netCDF.html#open-the-netcdf-file
There they've done as you've described.